# Is it possible to show actual numbers on the y axis for a barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, axis-labels, yaxis

I am analysing a sales dataset for an Uni Project in R and have run into the following problem, when making a barchart.

[barchart showcasing units sold by country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Q4Yj.png)

How can I let the actual numbers show on the y axis instead of "5e+05/ 1e+06"? Is it possible to have it show the actual numbers of the units (e.g for Germany it is 1.267.935,3) or to have it in steps shown, such as 1.250.000, 1.000.000, 750.000,...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
library(scales)

yourplot + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

Comment: We could use `scale_y_continuous (breaks = ..., labels =...)`